# WCF Service listening to multiple ports

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I need to install a WCF service on a single server but I need to listen to multiple ports (due to various issues with machines running the client).  It's not clear to me if this can be done with one `ServiceHost` and: one "class dervied from"(CDF) `ServiceBase` with two `endpoints`, or if I need two CDF `ServiceBase`s each with a single `endpoint`.  Here is the relevant code in relevant files:

Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new Service1()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

Service1.cs

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private wcfServer _server;
    ServiceHost serviceHost;

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(String[] args)
    {
        _server = new wcfServer();
        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(_server);
        serviceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
            serviceHost.Close();
    }
}
```

wcfServer.cs

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
    ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class wcfServer : IwcfServer { /* ... */ }
```

app.config

```
<services>
    <service name="MyService.wcfServer">
        <endpoint address=""
            bindingConfiguration="BigDataBinding"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="DataBackups.IwcfServer">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex"
            binding="mexHttpBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />

        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost/DataBackups/wcfServer/" />
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
    </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I should note that

1. the current "solution" to this issue is to alter the installer to allow us to install the service on the server *twice*.
2. the purpose of the service is to handle multiple concurrent requests that, in part, stream big data (in case this is relevant).

Can someone provide an example of how to accomplish this?

Also, I do not understand how `<service>` configurations in `app.config` relate to CDF `ServiceBase` instances created programmatically.  In the current setup, there is only a single `Service1` instance and a single configuration in `app.config`, so I imagine they "line up."  But, what if I there are multiple `Service1` instances (which I might need)?  How do I "choose" which service I am configuring?

Comment: `ServiceBase` is the base class that represents the function of a Windows service. This kind of service has absolutely nothing to do with what WCF calls a service -- an unfortunate case of overloading. Under normal circumstances, you implement only one service in an executable, and so will only ever have one `ServiceBase`-derived class. This service is then free to create multiple `ServiceHost` instances and/or host multiple endpoints for WCF services.

Comment: Agreed.  I have only one class derived from `ServiceBase` (`Service1`) and I want to have access to it from multiple ports (in particular `80` and the default `8732`).  Whether this means I have multiple `ServiceHost`s and/or `Service1`s and/or `endpoint`s is precisely my question.

Comment: Why dont you just setup a port forward on a firewall. Map the external ports to one internal port? This is way easier and much more configurable.

Comment: After even more testing, it turns out that port forwarding worked!  That machines that port forwarding did not work for turned out to have other networking issues that were causing problems.

As before, I will keep the question unanswered since it would be nice to see if this can be solved programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WCF` Service should have no issue listening on multiple ports.  You just need to expand the `baseAddress` section of your `app.config` file as follows:

```
<baseAddresses>
  <add baseAddress="http://localhost:80/DataBackups/wcfServer/" />
  <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/DataBackups/wcfServer/" />
</baseAddresses>
```

Comment: This does not work.  I've also tried adding these url's to two different `endpoint address=""` fields.  I've also tried just about every other combination of `baseaddress="http://localhost"` with `endpoint address` fields varying accordingly.  Some combinations fail on both ports, others fail on only a single port.